# Requesting user location in Swift

Tags: swift, gps, core-location

I am trying to get the pop up to appear for the user to allow location to be used and just cannot get it to work. I have gone into info.plist to add it to the "privacy - location always and when in use usage" and added the line '''CLLocationManager().requestWhenInUseAuthorization()'''
return true" in my ViewController which as far as I can find is all I need but it doesn't give the pop up. Anyone able to help?!

Comment: Are location settings on, either on the device or the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

in info.plist use these .It may help

Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

Comment: you have to add these 3 privacy in you plist. I hope it works for you.